# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer implicitly ignore some fields that are not excluded

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class GeneratedMessage(models.Model):
    generated_message_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    status = models.CharField(...)
    message_type = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(to=Prospect...)
    ai_prompt = models.ForeignKey(to=AiPrompt...)
```

And a model serializer:

```
class GeneratedMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GeneratedMessage
        exclude = ['prospect', 'ai_prompt']
        read_only_fields = ['__all__']
```

Actually, I use this serializer inside another one:

```
class GeneratedEmailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    body = GeneratedMessageSerializer()
    ...
```

This is the way I create a response:

```
class ProspectGenerateMessageAPI(APIView):
    ...
    @extend_schema(..., responses={200: GeneratedEmailSerializer})
    def post(self, request):
        ...
        generated_message.save()

        response = GeneratedEmailSerializer(data={
            ...
            "body": GeneratedMessageSerializer(generated_message).data
        })
        response.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return HttpResponse.ok(response.data)
```

However, the response has *no* field `body.generated_message_id` even though it was never excluded!
Other fields like the `body.status` are presented in the response.

Important facts:

- I find out in the Debug mode that `GeneratedMessageSerializer(generated_message).initial_data` have a valid id, while `GeneratedMessageSerializer(generated_message).data` not.
- Swagger docs generated by `@extend_schema` are somewhy correct with the field `generated_message_id`

Sadly, nested Serializers are barely mentioned in the documentation
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships